# nc: Proxy error: "HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"

Tags: ssh, proxy

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 x86_64. I am not able to ssh over proxy to remote host.

When I issued:

```
ssh -vl hackep6t 162.251.80.25
```

I got this output:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/rootkea/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec nc -X connect -x 192.168.5.254:3128 162.251.80.25 22
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1000
debug1: identity file /home/rootkea/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rootkea/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rootkea/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: identity file /home/rootkea/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rootkea/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rootkea/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1
nc: Proxy error: "HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Please help.

Comment: What do the logs on the server side say?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be connecting through an HTTP proxy (squid on port 3128), but nc's default connection protocol is SOCKS5.  I think you need to add `-X connect` to your `ProxyCommand` statement in ssh_config, to get nc to talk HTTP to your proxy.  See `man nc` for details.

Comment: I added `ProxyCommand nc -X connect -x 192.168.5.254:3128  %h %p` in ~/.ssh/config. Now it says `nc: Proxy error: "HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"` instead of `nc: read failed (0/3): Broken pipe` with all other messages as they are.

Comment: That's progress; at least you're speaking HTTP to your proxy now.  What do the squid logs say about why the request was denied?

Comment: I am not an admin of squid. It's institute wide proxy sever set up by our institute web admin. So I don't have access to squid logs.

Comment: Anyway your connection to squid is being denied.  You need help from the squid admins to get it to allow your connection.